# Is it possible to rename the features of an sklearn model after it was trained with other feature names?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I trained an sklearn `sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor` and would like to rename the input features to the model. I tried doing:
`model.feature_names_in_` = new feature names, but this doesn't work as I get:

`AttributeError: can't set attribute`

So is it just not possible?

EDIT:
After upgrading, this works:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression
import pandas as pd

X, y = make_regression(n_features=4, n_informative=2, random_state=0, shuffle=False)
regr = RandomForestRegressor(max_depth=2, random_state=0)
X = pd.DataFrame(X)
X.columns = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
regr.fit(X, y)
regr.feature_names_in_
```

```
array(["a", "b", "c", "d"], dtype=object)
```

```
regr.feature_names_in_ = ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd"]
regr.feature_names_in_
```

```
['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd']
```

Comment: What version of sklearn?

Comment: This works for me without error in 1.2.2 and 1.3.  Are you maybe using a pipeline?

Comment: @BenReiniger 1.1.2, but I upgraded to 1.3 and it's the same. Are you sure it worked with you? Did you maybe do something like `model.feature_names_in_[0] = new_name`? Because that "works" but it doesn't actually change the name

Comment: I did `model.feature_names_in_ = ["a", "b"]`. No error, and trying to predict on the original frame produced the expected error about wrong feature names.  Can you add a [mre] to the question?

Comment: Actually, I might have used the older version by accident when I commented. You're right, it works now. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**: As per the comments, setting the `feature_names_in_` attribute directly works. The problem was related to an older version of `sklearn`.

---

My original answer:

You could wrap the estimator in a custom one, like this:

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn.base import clone, BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin

#Class for renaming input features
class InputFeaturesRenamer(BaseEstimator, MetaEstimatorMixin):
    def __init__(self, estimator, renamed_features_dict):
        self.estimator = estimator
        self.renamed_features_dict = renamed_features_dict

    def _rename(self, X):
        X_renamed = X.copy()
        if hasattr(X, 'columns'):
            renamed_features = [
                self.renamed_features_dict[original_name]
                for original_name in X.columns
            ]
            X_renamed.columns = renamed_features
        return X_renamed

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        self.feature_names_in_ = X.columns.to_numpy()
        X_renamed = self._rename(X)

        #pass renamed X onto estimator
        self.estimator_ = clone(self.estimator).fit(X_renamed, y=y)

    def predict(self, X):
        X_renamed = self._rename(X)
        return self.estimator_.predict(X_renamed)

    def predict_proba(self, X):
        X_renamed = self._rename(X)
        return self.estimator_.predict_proba(X_renamed)
```

Test case:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({'feat0': [0,0,0,1], 'y': [2.1,2.2,2.2, 10]})

rf = RandomForestRegressor()
rf_renamed = InputFeaturesRenamer(rf, {'feat0': 'renamed_feat0'})
rf_renamed.fit(data[['feat0']], data.y)

print('Original names:', rf_renamed.feature_names_in_,
      'Renamed to:', rf_renamed.estimator_.feature_names_in_)
```

Output:

```
Original names: ['feat0'] Renamed to: ['renamed_feat0']
```

Renaming here only applies where the input is a dataframe. It feels like a complicated solution for a simple task, so I'd also be interested in seeing if there's a better way.

Answer (score 0):

In case anybody else still struggles with this. In case your estimator is a `sklearn.Pipeline`. The Pipeline `feature_names_in_` is a property, which returns the `steps[0][1].feature_names_in_`. The property cannot be set, but you can modify the `feature_names_in_` parameter of the first step of your pipeline and this will automatically propagate to the estimator property. In case you used `GridSearch`. The parameter `feature_names_in_` of the `GridSearch` object, needs to be updated manually, since it will not propagate the change.